# Button state activates on wrong cells

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview

I added button into cell-s and added action so if user touches it then the state is "Dislike" and if user touches again the state is "Like". However, the state applies to other cell buttons also. And if I scroll fast it just randomly picks what cell button should have the state. What causes this?

I call button with function inside `cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` function like this:

```
cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(like), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And this is the function that is assigned to the button:

```
func like(sender: UIButton){
    let section = 0
    let row = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
    let cell: FeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postsArray[indexPath.row].key).runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
            var stars : Dictionary<String, Bool>
            stars = post["stars"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
            var starCount = post["starCount"] as? Int ?? 0
            if let _ = stars[uid] {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                starCount -= 1
                stars.removeValue(forKey: uid)
                cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.likeButton.setTitle("Like", for: .normal)

                cell.likeLabel.text = "\(starCount)"
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                starCount += 1
                stars[uid] = true
                cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.likeButton.setTitle("Dislike", for: .normal)

                cell.likeLabel.text = "\(starCount)"
            }
            post["starCount"] = starCount as AnyObject?
            post["stars"] = stars as AnyObject?

            // Set value and report transaction success
            currentData.value = post

            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

And like this I created the tableview with cells:

```
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: FeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

        cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

What causes the state to transfer to the other buttons also? I even added tags so it detects the selected button. Is there something to do with cell reuse?

It adds likes to Firebase to the right one..

Comment: To answer your final question, in two words : cell reusing. You need to show us how you create and return the cells.

Comment: @Cyrille I edited.

Comment: If your like button is a direct child of your cell, you should try to get the `indexPath` by asking the table view instead of creating a new one based on the tag. `let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender.superview)`

Comment: Good point, I am gonna try that out tonight.

Comment: @Crazyrems still not working :(

Comment: I think you have to rewrite your like method. You should configure your cell inside `cellForRowAt` method, not somewhere else. Or you can modify your cell using blocks.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp try my code its 100 % working

Comment: You need to learn how tableViews work. "dequeueReusableCell" creates or dequeue a cell, it doesn't not necessarily reference any cell that is showing on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is because of dequeuing your cell twice. you should try;

```
func like(sender: UIButton){
    //your code ...
    let cell: FeedTableViewCell = self.tableViewAddress.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
    //Your code ...
```

Comment: That did the trick :O However now if I click fast 2 times it adds +2

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by reusing previous cells when scrolling and is the base mechanism of a table view.

You need to reset the state of your button on every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Between `let cell = ...` and `cell.starButton.addTarget` you need to perform something like `cell.starButton.deselect()`, or `.select()`, based on the index path you're working on.

Comment: I tried the `cell.starbutton.deselect` before calling the function, yes it doesn't select others now but it deselects it if it is out of view. But what do you mean with the "Based on the index path you're working on"?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var selectindex : Int?
  var selectedindex : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
  @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LikeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let like: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton)
        let comment: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton)
        if selectedindex.containsObject(indexPath.row) {
                like.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "like.png"), forState: .Normal)
        }else{
                like.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "like (1).png"), forState: .Normal)
        }
       comment.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "chat.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        like.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CloseMethod(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        comment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CloseMethod1(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        return cell

    }



 @IBAction func CloseMethod(sender: UIButton, event: AnyObject) {

        let touches = event.allTouches()!
        let touch = touches.first!
        let currentTouchPosition = touch.locationInView(self.tableview)
        let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForRowAtPoint(currentTouchPosition)!
        selectindex = indexPath.row
        if selectedindex.containsObject(selectindex!) {
            selectedindex.removeObject(selectindex!)
           // call your firebase method for update database 
        }else{
              selectedindex.addObject(selectindex!)
          // call your firebase method for update database
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
```

**Output** :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ub7wln5y6hdw0sz/like%20button.mov?dl=0

Comment: What button you have attatched to the CloseMethod func?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp like button . check my video