# Changing button background image when clicked UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView and each cell of the collection view has multiple buttons. I want to change the background image of the button that I click in a particular cell, just like how it works for like button in facebook app.

[image]

I have created a custom feed class and linked it to the cellForitemAt method:

```
let cell: FeedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

return cell
```

Feed Cell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell
{


    @IBOutlet weak var userNameText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var userProfilePic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var foodPic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var likePic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var likeText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dislikePic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var dislikeText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var favPic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var favText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentPic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var sharePic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var shareCount: UILabel!



 @IBAction func TempTest(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Pressed")
 }  
}
```

Could you please help me in achieving the same.

Thanks

Comment: Create __@IBAction__ in the cell class to change the colour of the button when pressed. Also override the __prepareForReuse__ method and reset button's background colour when it is reused for another __indexPath__.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40154725/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ub7wln5y6hdw0sz/like%20button.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following code.

Your UICollectionViewCell class

```
protocol FeedCellDelegate{
func didPress(with type:FeedCell.ClickedButtonType, senderImageView imageView:UIImageView, withcell cell:FeedCell)
}

class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
enum ClickedButtonType {
    case userProfilePic,foodPic,likePic,likeText,dislikePic,favPic,commentPic,sharePic
}

var delegate : FeedCellDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var userNameText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var userProfilePic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var foodPic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var likePic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var likeText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var dislikePic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var dislikeText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var favPic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var favText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var commentPic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var commentText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sharePic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var shareCount: UILabel!


@IBAction func TempTest(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Call the delegate method and pass the values according to your action just for example i have used commentPic state you can put a switch case or if-else
    delegate?.didPress(with: .commentPic, senderImageView: commentPic, withcell: self)
}
}
```

and your view controller.

```
//Your controller implements FeedCellDelegate
class YourViewController : UIViewController,FeedCellDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var collectionView : UICollectionView!
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1//Use your array to return the count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: FeedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func didPress(with type:FeedCell.ClickedButtonType, senderImageView imageView:UIImageView, withcell cell:FeedCell){
    //Get the indexPath
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
    //remove the break and put all other enum cases and you can handle the cases and change the image according to your logic
    switch type {
    case .userProfilePic: break
    default: break
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting the error at line  cell.delegate = self   "Value of type 'FeedCell' has no member 'delegate'.

Comment: Check out var delegate : FeedCellDelegate? below the enum that i have declared did you put that in your code?

Comment: I had forgotten that. I have written a print statement in one of the switch case, but I am not getting any output for the same.

Comment: is your TempTest getting called?