# Change custom tableview cell's image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**My situation :** I make a custom cell named: `BestQuestionListCell` and I create a `tableview` in `BestQuestionListViewController`. In `BestQuestionListCell` I add a button on left. And I setImage on the `button`. Now when I tap the cell the image of the `button` does change. Now I want set one of these cell as selected when the view show up.

I tried to set image of button and I also tried to set the cell as selected. Either of them didn't work.

**UISreenShot :** [The screenshot of BestQuestionListViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Aau.png)

**Here is the code of tableViewcell.**

```
@implementation BestQuestionListCell
@synthesize questionLabel;
@synthesize authorLabel;
@synthesize ownerButton;
@synthesize starButton;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"I am selected! %@",selected?@"yes":@"no");
//    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        [self.starButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fstar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [self.starButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Star"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

- (void)setButtonImage:(UIImage *)buttonImage{
    _buttonImage = buttonImage;
    [self.starButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fstar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    NSLog(@"nothing happened? %@",buttonImage);
}
```

**And here is the tableview.**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifer = @"BestQuestionListCell";
    BestQuestionListCell *mainCell = (BestQuestionListCell *)[self.bestQuestionListTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer];

    if(mainCell == nil) {
        mainCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifer owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    }

    if ( [DataSession sharedSession].subQuestionArray.count > 0) {
        mainCell.questionLabel.text = [[DataSession sharedSession].subQuestionArray[indexPath.row] question_content];
        mainCell.questionLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74/255.0f green:74/255.0f blue:74/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        mainCell.questionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                mainCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
    return mainCell;
}
```

**I didn't do anything in**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I tried these three ways to solve this issue but didn't work.

```
[mainCell setButtonImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fstar"]];
[mainCell.starButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fstar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mainCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: By the way, I use xib too.

Comment: when you selectedrowindex method call then just set one thing that is [mainCell setSelected:YES animated:YES]; this for particular cell and remove that line in cellForRowAtIndexPath and in selectedrow just reload your table

Comment: you could write only [mainCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];

Comment: @KayaZhou brother did you show some ui that show your table and your image . that you change

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40154725/6656894 refer this answer for your solution.

Comment: [mainCell setSelected:YES animated:YES]; doesn't work when I try to set first row to be selected .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya The image did changed when I click the row of tableview. So I think both the table and the image is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per your edited question below is the code work. I have done code commenting so that you can understand code properly, if still you have issue you can ask.

```
#import "BestQuestionListVC.h"
#import "BestQuestionListCell.h"

@interface BestQuestionListVC () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSArray *arrQuesList;
    NSArray *arrAuthorList;
    NSMutableArray *arrMutBtnSelected; // arrMut of bools, containing true/false of button as selected or not.

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblBestQuestion;


@end

@implementation BestQuestionListVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // creating temp array of data
    arrQuesList     = @[@"ques #1", @"ques #2", @"ques #3", @"ques #4", @"ques #5", @"ques #6", @"ques #7", @"ques #8" ];
    arrAuthorList   = @[@"Author #1", @"Author #2", @"Author #3", @"Author #4", @"Author #5", @"Author #6", @"Author #7", @"Author #8" ];

    arrMutBtnSelected = [NSMutableArray new];  // alloc Mutable array

    // array of bools, initially all false as not any button is selected
    for (int i=0; i < arrQuesList.count; i++) {
        [arrMutBtnSelected addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
    }

    // for initially first button is selected.
    [arrMutBtnSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnStarClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    // If one button is selected at one time
    // start
    /*
         [arrMutBtnSelected removeAllObjects];
         for (int i=0; i < arrQuesList.count; i++) {
         [arrMutBtnSelected addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
         }
         [arrMutBtnSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]];
    */
    // end

    // if user can selects multiple buttons
    // start
    /*
        if (sender.selected) {
            [arrMutBtnSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
        }
        else{
            [arrMutBtnSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]];
    }
    */
    // end

    [self.tblBestQuestion reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - TableViewDelegate

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return arrQuesList.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BestQuestionListCell *quesCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BestQuestionListCell"];

    quesCell.lblQuestion.text   = arrQuesList[indexPath.row];
    quesCell.lblAuthor.text     = arrAuthorList[indexPath.row];
    quesCell.btnStar.tag = indexPath.row ;

    if (arrMutBtnSelected[indexPath.row] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]) {
        quesCell.btnStar.selected = true;
    }
    else{
        quesCell.btnStar.selected = false;
    }

    return quesCell;
}

@end
```

**OUTPUT :**

**Initially when project runs :**

[image]

**Output for if user selects one button at a time :**

[image]

**Output for if user selects any multiple buttons**

[image]

Comment: I try to make the first row be selected when I show this tableview. like this:

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [mainCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
        }else{
            [mainCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
        }
It doesn't work.

Comment: Because you are not listening to me.

Comment: I tried your solution but still doesn't work. Same result that the image did change when I tapped the row, but I can't set it manually.

Comment: Why you need to set image manually, as you saying image is changing when you tapped on row. This is your requirement. If your need is changed then pls specify. And let me know.

Comment: sorry for the miss leading. Now I can change image when I tapped. My requirement is when the tableview show up at first time, I want make one of this row being selected and show the image "Fstar". Thanks man.

Comment: What is the current output of your code, I will proceed according to that.

Comment: Post it as a question not answer otherwise your question will be blocked by someone. And second thing instead of explaining that much just post your UI image, we can understand more accurately.

Comment: Thank you for notification. I upload UI image. Hope it helps.

Comment: @KayaZhou Check my edited output, if you have issue you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //you could write only
 [mainCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry, Jignesh, I try to set the first row be selected when the tableview show up, but this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.Please try it.

```
First set the IBOutLet in the tableViewCell.
```

Then in the viewController: at the cellForRowAtIndexPath method you can write this way:

```
UIImage *imageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your selected img name"];
UIImage *imageNotSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your not selected img name"];
[cell.yourBtnName setImage:imageNotSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.yourBtnName setImage:imageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[cell.yourBtnName addTarget:self action:@selector(yourBtnClickMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in action method:

```
-(void)yourBtnClickMethod:(UIButton *)btn{
    btn.selected = !btn.selected;
}
```

Hope it helps for you.Thanks